# How to Solve this Non-linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ode $x^2y^{''}(x)-2y(x)-2=0$, I was trying to introduce a variable $z(x)=y'(x)$ but it seems that this doesn't help. Any other simple ways?

Comment: This is actually a linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous equation 
$$x^2y''(x)-2y(x)=0$$
is a special case of an Euler-Cauchy equation, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Try looking for solutions of the form $y(x)=x^r$.

To solve the general equation, you'll need a particular solution, but there is a rather obvious one (try $y(x)=$ constant).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a non-linear equation, btw.  It is an Euler equation. First solve the related homogeneous equation. Assume a solution of the form $y=x^r$.  Then you get

$$x^2r(r-1)x^{r-2} -2x^r = 0.$$

Divide by $x^r$ to see that $r(r-1)-2 = r^2-r-2 = (r+1)(r-2) = 0$.  Conclude that $y_c = c_1x^{-1}+c2x^{2}$.

Now use variation of parameters to solve the non-homogeneous equation.

Actually, it's quicker to follow Olivier Moschetta's advice.  By inspection, a non-homogeneous solution is $y_p = -1.$  So final general solution is $y_c+y_p$.